# How to use different instances of service without parent-child relationship?

Tags: angular

Providers declared in given component with `viewProviders` are accessible by the component itself and all of its view successors. But they need have parent-child relationship.

However, right now I have 4 **components A, B, C, D**, and 1 **service E**.

These components have no parent-child relationship.

How can I let A and B use one instance of this service, C and D use another instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class `class F extends E` and request `E` in `A` and `B`, `F` in `C` and `D`. You could also register `E` with different tokens and request the tokens in the constructors instead of the type.